# Reading QR Codes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bitmap, zxing, hololens

I'm currently working on a project reading QR codes with the Microsoft Hololens. I'm developing the application in Unity (5.4.0 build 24) in C# and I'm using ZXing to read the QR codes. I downloaded ZXing from [this webpage](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com) and I ended up using the .NET 3.5 version. I was able to generate a byte array corresponding to the view of the Hololens. I then want to use the decode function to get the text in the QR code:

```
ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode(img_bitmap);
```

However, in order to use this, I need to create a `Bitmap`, which is included in `System.Drawing`. As I understand, Unity3D doesn't include this package, so I followed the instructions in [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/253571/view.html) and included `System.Drawing` from .NET 2.0. However, when I try to build, I get the following error:

```
error CS7069: Reference to type 'MarshalByRefObject' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found.
```

According to my understanding, Unity builds to .NET 3.5, but I've been unable to find a .NET 3.5 version of `System.Drawing` on my system (and I'm not convinced this is the root of the problem anyway). Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unity 5 is using custom version of mono compiler. Some of the libraries are cut from standard .Net 3.5.

Comment: Hmm ok, do you know how I could go about fixing this error so I can use bitmaps?

Comment: I do not have any experience about this. You should ask this question on Unity which have more experience programmer.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I get an answer there and if so update this post

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

- use Texture2D to store your image
- get pixels from that image using method GetPixels32()
- send these pixels to Decode-method.

So, you make a Texture2D variable:

```
public Texture2D image;
```

Then, in a method somewhere, you type in something like this:

```
var codeReader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true };
codeReader.Options.TryHarder = true;

var decodeResult = codeReader.Decode(image.GetPixels32(), image.width, image.height);
```

Dunno much about ZXing yet, but hopefully some people find this helpful. :)